# removing very first token of a file only

Tags: regex, bash

i am not much familiar in scripting. it can be very easy problem. I want to remove first token of every file.

```
  file 1

 1 this is good


  file 2
  2 this is another file.
```

i would like to remove 1 and 2 from file 1 and file 2. how would do it? any bash command for it?

Answer (score 2):

Or with awk:

```
$ awk '{if (NR==1) {$1="";print $0;} else print $0}' input_file
```

(This preserves the space at the start of the line)

Comment: You can do that shorter: `awk 'NR==1 {$1=""}; print' input_file`

Comment: Indeed, this is shorter, except my awk seems to require extra curly brackets:     `awk 'NR==1 {$1=""};{print}' input_file`

Comment: No, no,... not just your awk...this was an error of mine!! but one can fix the error and shorten further:

`awk 'NR==1 {$1=""}; 1' input_file`

Comment: :) I think that one is _unshortenable_.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed and assuming you don't want to preserve a leading space:

```
sed '1{s/\s*\w*//}' input_file
```

This will works on the very first line (`1{}`) and uses substitute command (`s/pattern/replace/`) to delete the first white spaces and following word characters (`\s*\w*`). The word characters are [a-zA-Z0-9].

Comment: could you please add your explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '0,/1/{s/1//}' f1 
  this is good
```

Comment: there can be anything in the position of 1 and 2